# NoraUI - How to skip a scenario test?

Tags: noraui

I'm looking for a tag like "ignore" to skip a scenario test in NoraUI.

I tried this but it is not working :

```
@ignore
Scenario: 1 - Renvoi d’un rejet de mouvement Reflex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not need add all run scenario tags in `--tags` of Maven command

sample:

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @hello,@bye,@Tag5,@tag10"
```

You can run all scenarios without some scenarios:

```
 --tags ~@todo --tags ~@wip
```

full official notice [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags)

**Be careful**, in NoraUi 3.x.x use io.cucumber => syntax change:

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags '@hello or @bye or @Tag5 or @tag10'"
```

Comment: Thanks that's the solution I was looking for.
It is quite convenient for running only some specific scenarios in different feature files having the same tag. I will now use after each update of my web application !